# GDB Displacement Command

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering, disassembly

How would I get the value at

```
0x14(%esp,%ebx,4)
```

in GDB?

I have tried `p/x 0x14(%esp,%ebx,4)` and get the error

```
A syntax error in expression, near `%esp,%ebx,4)'
```

Answer (score 1):

%esp+4*%ebx+0x14
It's calculating from that formula
offset(base, index, muliplier)
address = base + index*multiplier + offset